# Concatenate two columns of spark dataframe with null values

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, concatenation

I have two columns in my spark dataframe

```
First_name  Last_name
Shiva       Kumar
Karthik     kumar
Shiva       Null
Null        Shiva
```

My requirement is to add a new column to dataframe by concatenating the above 2 columns with a comma and handle null values too.

I have tried using concat and coalesce but I can't get the output with comma delimiter only when both columns are available

Expected output

```
Full_name
Shiva,kumar
Karthik,kumar
Shiva
Shiva
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`concat_ws` concats and handles `null` values for you.

```
df.withColumn('Full_Name', F.concat_ws(',', F.col('First_name'), F.col('Last_name'))
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`lit`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.lit):

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

f = df.withColumn('Full_Name', F.concat(F.col('First_name'), F.lit(','), F.col('Last_name'))).select('Full_Name')

# fix null values
f = f.withColumn('Full_Name', F.regexp_replace(F.col('Full_Name'), '(,Null)|(Null,)', ''))

f.show()

+-------------+
|    Full_Name|
+-------------+
|  Shiva,Kumar|
|Karthik,kumar|
|        Shiva|
|        Shiva|
+-------------+
```

Comment: Will this handle the 'null' values ?

Comment: just added that part.